# How to find what depends on a specific version of a specific dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, dependencies

I'm getting this error when I run my app (not at compile time):

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor, Version=2.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

My solution has many projects, using project references where possible, but some of those projects have assembly references to external dependencies.

How can I easily find out which project is looking for this specific version of `Castle.Windsor.dll`?  I don't have that version and am trying to use 2.5.2 (latest), so I want to find the culprit and update it to use the latest one.

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I've added a sanitised Fusion log below. It appears to be telling me that `Caliburn.Castle` requires `Castle.Windsor, Version=2.1.0.0` (which would be a mistake as I'm using 2.5), but Fusion assembly probing as actually finding `Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0` instead.

Have I understood that correctly?

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Barney\neil
LOG: DisplayName = Castle.Windsor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///[Debug folder of my exe]
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = [Filename of my exe]
Calling assembly : Caliburn.Castle, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: [Config file for my exe]
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Castle.Windsor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[Debug folder of my exe]/Castle.Windsor.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: [Debug folder of my exe]\Castle.Windsor.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: You are correct, a newer version of Castle.Windsor is being found, but Caliburn.Castle wants an older version.

Comment: @Pedro Yeah, I've since used Reflector to look at Caliburn.Castle.dll, and found it requires 2.1 of Castle.Windsor.dll (despite me rebuilding from source). I'll have another go at building Caliburn.Castle.dll with an updated Castle and try again. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [Fuslogvw.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) which will provide you more information on the calling assembly. Scott Hansleman also [blogged about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the assembly binding log viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)?

This should provide all the information needed.

See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[FusionLog tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) is best tool for things like that, but sometimes will only point to your code. Try turning up the verbosity for MSBuild and you might be able to track it down to where the compilation is at when it fails.