# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity'

Tags: c#, assembly-loading

I am trying to upgrade `Unity` to version (2.1.505.2), but when I run the application I get the following `FileLoadException`

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity,
>   Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   or one of its dependencies.

We are upgrading from Unity 2.0.414.0 to 2.1.505.2.

- All project references in the solution that refer to Unity refer to the correct version of the dll
- There is no Unity dll referenced in the Gac. (double checked by checking `gacutil -l`)
- I removed all Unity dlls from the archive. Double checked with powershell

  ```
  PS C:\> ls -rec -inc Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll | foreach-object { "{0}`t{1}" -f $_.FullName, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_).FileVersion }
  ```

How can I find out what / who still refers to the Unity 2.0.414.0?

FusionLogVw doesn't tell me which DLL is causing the problem.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was another Microsoft dll that refers to the old version of unity. I found this out be accident be checking the namespaces of every referenced dll, and found another dll that contained namespaces with "unity".

Updating:

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation

to latest released versions resolved the problem.

I hope I save the day for some lost soul out there who's also pulling his hair out over this issue... :)

Answer (score 4):

The binding redirect should be pointed to a proper assembly version.

For your case **version 2.1.505.0** should be used!

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.505.0" newVersion="2.1.505.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

**2.1.505.2** cannot be specified because of next reason:

[image]

Unity assembly **2.1.505.2** has different versions specified in the **AssemblyFileVersion** and **AssemblyVersion**.

CLR is working with the **AssemblyVersion** and **AssemblyFileVersion** is ignored but NuGet is working with the **AssemblyFileVersion**!

So that's why you have this difference!

Please use **AssemblyVersion**

Comment: Thank you for this, was about to lose it over it not finding 2.1.505.2 when the version in properties is 2.1.505.2.

Answer (score 0):

Since your new question is about finding existing dependencies on an assembly, you might refer to this question:

[How to find what depends on a specific version of a specific dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877997/how-to-find-what-depends-on-a-specific-version-of-a-specific-dependency)

Which refers to using [Fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have resharper, you can remove the problem reference, build, goto the class where it is used(there is an error) and get resharper to fix it for you.

Saves faffing around, but I appreciate not everyone has resharper :D

Answer (score 0):

**Overview:**
this was someone's code I had to fix a bug in code, so they provided me a zip file of application.

I had no Idea what was happening and why always for the first time my code was running and after restart the application (post any changes) it start throwing Exception.
there are many possible solution provided in the forums and i was blaming my code & database and then started undo each step i did. But that doesn't help

**Solution:**
As multiple troubleshoot can't fix this 
but when I restarted investigate each n every thing from beaning  to find the actual reason which is causing the exception, I found is

**For every new build, my application's bin folder deleting the dlls**

> then the solution is to paste these dlls into applications bin folder and rebuild the code
>   (refer screenshot)

**result**: all sh*t gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to correct it by using the EnterpriseLibrary update in the accepted solution.  I ended up just overriding the dependent assembly version in the **app.config**, you could do something similar to force any library that complains about the version to use another version.

App.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Unity.Container" publicKeyToken="489B6ACCFAF20EF0" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.8.11.0" newVersion="5.8.11.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your app.config/web.config and of course your project references.

Comment: done that already, thoroughly. I am convinced nothing refers to 2.0.414. Something else is pulling in that depenency, and runtime is complaining that it, as mentioned in the exception, simply can't find the no longer existing version of the assembly.